# What are the OIDs (KU and EKU) necessary for Smart Card Authentication in Windows?

Tags: windows, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, smartcard

MSFT smart card authentication is listed in [PKINIT RFC 4556](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4556.txt) however I don't see any OIDs listed.

Based on [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959887) and [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955558) KB article the EKU section of the certificate should contain "Client Authentication" or "Microsoft smart card".

I believe I found the OID of the EKU section [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291010)

```
OID=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2       ; XCN_OID_PKIX_KP_CLIENT_AUTH  Client Authentication (KB291010)
```

I also found a list of possible OIDs [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287547)

```
 OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2  ; XCN_OID_KP_SMARTCARD_LOGON
```

What are the requirements for SmartCard encryption with Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the requirements are listed in this KB article
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281245

The smart card certificate has specific format requirements:

The CRL Distribution Point (CDP) location (where CRL is the Certification Revocation List) must be populated, online, and available.

**For example:**

CRL Distribution Point
Distribution Point Name:
Full Name: URL=http://server1.name.com/CertEnroll/caname.crl

Key Usage = Digital Signature

Basic Constraints [Subject Type=End Entity, Path Length Constraint=None] (Optional)

Enhanced Key Usage =

Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
(The client authentication OID) is only required if a certificate is used for SSL authentication.)

Smart Card Logon (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2)

Subject Alternative Name = Other Name: Principal Name= (UPN). For example:

UPN = user1@name.com

The UPN OtherName OID is : "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3"

The UPN OtherName value: Must be ASN1-encoded UTF8 string

Subject = Distinguished name of user. This field is a mandatory extension, but the population of this field is optional.